# VBA Outlook Macro: How many E-Mails does a Folder contain?

Tags: vba, outlook

Goal: an Outlook-VBA macro thas looks through every available folder and checks if it contains a mail message or not. If not, the user can decide to delete the folder. Is there any way to do this?

```
Sub findAndDeleteEmptyFolders()

Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders
Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim FoundMail As Boolean

Set Folders = Application.Session.Folders


For Each F In Folders
    Dim FItems As Integer
    FItems = F.Items.count

    MsgBox ("Der Ordner: " & F.Name & " hat " & FItems & " Items")
Next

End Sub
```

So this code just looking into the top folders, but not into the folders like "Inbox". It gives out that every active mail account has 0 Mails, but there are like 9000 Mails in some of them...how can I look, lets say, deeper into the folders (subfolders?).

Comment: Yes, there is a way. But if you want us to help, you're going to have to be more precise than "not working very well". Please edit your question to clearly indicate what problem you are running into.

Comment: I just found a solution by myself, but Iam still open for new ideas :)

Comment: For the benefit of other users, please post your solution as an answer. That way you may also get feedback on your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all folders and items in Outlook is not a good idea. If you need to find items that satisfy to your conditions you can use the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods. The following articles describe them in depth:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

But if you need to find items in all folders I'd suggest using the AdvancedSearch method of the Application class. See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.